# Is it possible to retrieve objects in use from memory of a Next.js/React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, reverse-engineering, react-devtools

I am building an web-based editor and I came across a live website that has a similar approach to my idea. I want to see the structure of objects they are using to create components, or to see the React states/onChange handlers. Is it possible to see the implementations of these functions in the bundle/react dev tools or the memory heap snapshot?

Using React Dev Tools I can see a ton of ContextProviders, some have values, some functions, but the functions only have their names displayed

How to dive deep into how the values are being used in the website? Is it possible to find its corresponding consumer kind of how you can hover an HTML element in the tree and see it highlight in the website?

[image: Here is a sample view from react dev tools]